# Empty Response Post CreateToken YouTrack Hub

Tags: post, token, youtrack

I'm trying to use YouTrack's Rest API to create a token via API for a specific user. See documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/HUB-REST-API_Users_Post-CreateToken.html

All other POST and GET queries work perfectly. But for Post Create Token, I get back an empty JSON. However, the status of the request is 200.

Content for POST
{"email":"xy", "group":"All Users", "baseUrl":"xy", "redirectUrl":"./hub/"}

I would expect a response with user and token.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

To create a permanent token please [use this endpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/HUB-REST-API_Users_Permanent-Tokens-of-User_Add-Permanent-Token-to-Permanent-Tokens-of-a-User.html).

Comment: As I understand, this endpoint is to add an existing token to a user. I want to create a token for a user or create a token and add it to a user. But I cannot create a token via API at the moment.

Comment: this endpoint both creates and attaches a permanent token to a particular user. You may double-check that by opening the browser's network tools while creating a permanent token from UI

Comment: Got it, thank you!

URL
https://{baseURL}/hub/api/rest/users/{userid}/permanenttokens?failOnPermissionReduce=true&fields=token

Request Body
{"scope":[{"id":"{userid}","key":"{userid}","label":"YouTrack","data":{"id":"{userid}","name":"YouTrack","applicationName":"YouTrack"}},{"id":"0-0-0-0-0","key":"0-0-0-0-0","label":"YouTrack Administration","data":{"id":"0-0-0-0-0","name":"YouTrack Administration","applicationName":"Hub"}}],"name":"Test"}